# ¿Cómo estilizar el boton de login de facebook en android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Tengo el boton que proporciona facebook en su  documentación, pero mi duda es ¿Cómo lograr modificar ese botón para que se vea como yo quiero?

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramses, me parece que te refieres a "personalizar" el boton, lo puedes realizar agregando la propiedad `style` a tu boton:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"/>
```

y crea un `style` en donde defines las propiedades del boton:

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/smallTxtSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/facebook_signin_btn</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

Esta propuesta se encuentra en el sitio SO en ingles propuesta por @filsh

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19179856/250260

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar un Botón de Inicio con Facebook de acuerdo al sdk 4.x

> **Clase** **LoginManager**: permite comenzar inicios de sesión sin usar ningún elemento de la interfaz de usuario.

URL: [Facebook Login Android.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

Lo cual permite obtener un inicio de sesion sin la utilizacion del boton contenido por defecto en el SDK

```
com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

Siendo así, primero define tu botón como lo quieras.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/mi_boton_facebook"
            .../>
```

Y después activa `LoginManager` cuando este botón sea presionado.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inicio Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        Button mButtonFacebook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mi_boton_facebook);

        mi_boton_facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });

    }

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```